# ¿Cómo usar JSON_SEARCH dentro de JSON_EXTRACT en MySQL (con ruta dinámica)?

Tags: mysql, sql, json, mariadb, jsonarray

Buen día
Tengo una situación.
tengo un campo tipo json array y necesito acceder a un campo con su respectivo index
ej:
la tabla bill tiene un campo details que es de tipo json array y en una de sus iteraciones arroja algo como esto:

```
[
   {
      "id":"6",
      "code":"85967412",
      "name":"ASROCK RX VII 16GB",
      "unitCost":2998800,
      "quantity:"2"
   },
   {
      "id":"7",
      "code":"32+612",
      "name":"CAMARA LOGITECH C920",
      "unitCost":257040,
      "quantity:"3"
   },
   {
      "id":"8",
      "code":"8796587",
      "name":"COOLER MASTER MASTERCASE H500P MESH GUN ME",
      "unitCost":785400,
      "quantity:"4"
   }
]
```

Y requiero que muestre la cantidad cuando el **code es es 32+612** en todas la iteraciones pero no se como redactar la consulta, intente con JSON_SEARCH y JSON_EXTRACT pero aun no lo consigo.

para el caso específico de esta iteración sería algo como esto:

```
SELECT details->>'$[1].code' as Code FROM bills
```

sin embargo en las otras iteraciones el índice del objeto json será diferente.

¿Cómo podría construir la consulta?

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Imagina este escenario `WHERE campotipojson LIKE '%"code":"32+612"%'` con seguridad te devuelve los registros que contengan objetos json en los que haya un atributo code = "32+612" y no te complicas la vida. Luego los puedes filtrar.

Comment: Si necesitas usar específicamente métodos ligados con JSON debes leer : [json-search-functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html)